# Проблемы с отображением русских символов php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Сделал сайт с php, на локалке все работало отлично, после того как загрузил на хостинге все русские символы из бд на сайте в виде вопрсов, а при создание новых данных в бд они отображаются как иероглифы, но при этом на сайте отображаются русскими буквами. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: не правильно работаешь с кодировками, возможно когда заливал дамп или создавал бд/таблицы ввел не полный DDL

Comment: Я уже что только не проверил, но самое странное на другом хостинге данные отображаются и добавляются верно, но авторизация работает в 1 из 50 раз, совершенно случайным образом

Comment: потому что разные конфиги пхп на разных хостингах, разные кодировки по-умолчанию.